# ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property is empty

Tags: c#, process

I am writing a keep-alive service to see if a process is up and running. I have several processes with the same name running out of different working directories.

I would, therefore, like to use the [`WorkingDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property as a unique identifier. However, when I interrogate all these properties, the value is empty.

Here's some code:

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory))
        Console.WriteLine("Winning!!!");
```

Needless to say, I'm not winning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **Process.MainModule** and the **ProcessModule.FileName** property.

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    string executableFilePath = process.MainModule.FileName;
    string executableDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(executableFilePath);
}
```

Be aware, that a process could exit anytime. If coincidentally the process' MainModule is queried while the process is exiting (or has exited), then an exception is thrown.